# Is it possible to have a Mac drive a display as a mirror image (and not simply rotated)

Tags: mac, screen

I need to flip the screen of Mac X 10.4 either vertically or horizontally. I should emphasis that I do not want to rotate 180 degree I want to have mirrored output. Is there any way of driving a Mac's display as a mirror image (and not simply rotated)?

Several answers have jumped on rotation, so *please don't confuse rotation with actual flipping*. A mirror image (either vertical or horizontal) distorts text in a similar manner to taking a sheet of nearly transparent paper and literally flipping it so you see the words from behind the paper.

Here is an illustration of rotation (not what this question seeks)
: rotate display 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

[image]

What I seek is horizontal display flip.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to flip an built-in display (like on an iMac or MacBook), or an external display?

I'm afraid it's only possible to flip an external display. Here's how to do that (tested with 10.6, but 10.4 should be similar):

Go to System Preferences-> Displays. Go to the Display tab of your external monitor's window. For `Rotation:` select either 90 or 270.

You can still mirror your displays.

Comment: I want to flip the built-in display.
Also for the external display, you have mentioned about the rotation, but how flipping is possible?

Comment: @Reza as I said, you can't change the internal one. You can't flip any display; the closest you can get is rotating.

Comment: 10.4 is pretty much exactly the same.